# Save Results of a SQL Query to an Excel File

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL Query I'm using to Pull Beds by Unit and the related Number of Beds in Use and Available.

What is the SQL Syntax to have the results of the query save to an excel file (existing or new).

Please Note: I have been searching and I can't believe this isn't easy to figure out. Lots of people seems to use other tools but I want to do it in SQL Stored Procedure - Is this possible?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I am using Windows 7, Excel 2010, SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: It may be easier to start in excel and drop your query into a database connection, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Generally, you cannot write to files directly from SQL commands in SQL Server/T-SQL.  SQL Server intends that you other means/utilities/sql-tools to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easier way to do this is from Excel, utilize a connection to your SQLDB and then pull the data into excel, that is the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This is the conclusion that I came to as well.